# Access: How to add additional column values to a diagram?

Tags: sql, ms-access, diagram

I want to visualize some results of my DB in a diagramm.

The diagram has the following values:

- x-coordinate = time
- y-coordinate = amount (production)
- bars = show the amount of the produced product

**The Problem is:**

Now I want to show the production maximum per month with a line graph. So i need to add additional column values to the diagram.

Does it have something to do with the PIVOT value in the SQL Code of the Diagram?

thx

Comment: Are you able to picturize the scenario?

Comment: If you already have the production amount over time then you shouldn't need any additional values to produce a line graph with maximum per month.

Comment: @Keppy: The diagram should look like this http://peltiertech.com/Excel/pix1/AddLine.gif --> blue bars show the actual production, blue line shows the maximum...